# Allow access to storage account from old Cloud Service (classic) in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services

I'm setting a storage account to allow access from certain IPs and subnets only. In the networking configuration for the storage account, I added allowed IP addresses - there are 3 so far.  Once done and saved, I can now access the storage account from those 3 IP addresses, but not from anywhere else.

Now, I have an old Cloud Service (classic) - it's due to be migrated to ARM, but not yet, there are reasons for that.  I need to grant worker roles access to this storage account. If I RDP to a worker instance and run a browser there, I can see my "external" IP address - so I added this address to the allowed addresses on the storage account. Yet, connections from cloud storage to this storage account are denied.

I suspect this is because Azure is routing the traffic from the cloud service to the storage account internally - and storage account doesn't see it as coming from the internet - but I can't think what I can do about it.

Note that this cloud service is VERY old (nearly 10 years old). It's not in any vnet presently.

So, how can I grant access to this storage account from this cloud service?

**UPDATE:** I created a classic virtual network to deploy the cloud service into, however I cannot select a classic virtual network in the storage account network configuration - it's simply not listed there.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual Network (Classic) won't be available directly on storage account network configuration.  In-order to do this we need to **migrate** that **Virtual Network (Classic)** one to **Migrate to ARM**

Steps are below.

1. Created a storage account along with classic Virtual Network (Classic)
   [image]
2. Click on **Migrating to ARM**
   [image]
3. Click on Validate and proceed with steps and commit.

[image]

4. Upon migration a new Virtual Network will be create.

[image]
[image]

5. Go to Storage Account, under Networking we can select **"Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses"** option and select newly created Virtual Network from the list.

[image]
6. Now we can be able to access Storage account as expected.

Comment: You clearly missed the main point of my question. I cannot migrate the classic network to ARM, because it contains classic resources that cannot be migrated to ARM. My question is about allowing classic resources to access ARM storage account.

Comment: refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-errors

Step-by-Step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/canitpro/step-by-step-migrate-your-classic-cloud-services-to-arm-storage-migration

Comment: Only option to allowing classic resources to access our Storage account is Migrate to ARM. Gone through all possible options.  Upon migration it will allow as mentioned in step 5.